# How to extract json string value in scala

Tags: scala

So i have a json file in which i have schema like this:

```
{
   "Field": "{\"key1\":\"Value1\",\"key2\":\"Value2\"}
}
```

I want to extract value of key1 & key2 which is Value1 & Value2

Comment: what json library are you using? what have you already tried?

Comment: As of now, i am not using any external library. I am planning to derive it using scala.

Comment: You should have a look into using an external library. For example, io.circe

Comment: I am using liftweb can you help with this?